# Django: Default ImageField Return

Tags: python, django

I have a Django `ImageField` with `djangorestframework`, and I want it to return a default image if it's none. How can I return an image from my `staticfiles` to replace this?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    ...

    def get_image(self):
        """
        Returns an image, or the default image.
        """
        if not self.image:
            # what goes here? <---
        return self.image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set **`default`** in model field.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(default='path/to/static/image.jpg')
```

---

Update-1

```
from django.conf import settings


class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    ...

    def get_image(self):
        if not self.image:
            return f'{settings.STATIC_URL}sample/img/default.png'
        return self.image.url
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to reference static files from the python side? I know you can do {% static %} on the template side, but is there an equivalent from the python side?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't set the default on the model, because I need to be able to check that the ImageField is none. I just need a way to return an image from the get_image method.

Comment: check my Update-1 section

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
class The_image_model(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)
    ...
```

views.py

```
def get_the_image(request):
    get_images = The_image_model.objects.all()
    ...
return render(request, 'imageTemplate.html', {'get_images':get_images})
```

In imageTemplate.html:

```
{% load static %}


{% if get_images.images.url  %}
   <img class="img-fluid rounded mb-3 mb-md-0" src="{{ get_images.images.url}}" 
alt="">
{% else %}
   <img class="img-fluid rounded mb-3 mb-md-0" src="{% static 'image/empty-image.jpg' %}" 
alt="">
{% endif %}
```